# how to dynamically compare a value, such as 2 with "<10", since 2<10, so return true?

Tags: scala

I have the following map and list

```
val a=Map(1->"<10",2->"<20")
val b=List((1,15),(2,15))
```

get the tuples from b:
use the first element of the tuple to look up the map, and compare the second element, if it matches then pick it up:

e.g 
for tuple of (1,15), lookup the map we get "<10", and then compare the second element which 15 with "<10", it failed, so throw this tuple away.
for tuple of (2,15), we will compare 15 with "<20", it's correct, so keep the tuple of (2,14).

Is it doable in scala?

Comment: Is the question how to parse the string "<10" into a function {x < 10} ?

Comment: “I saw the best minds of my generation ruined by dynamic languages” … With deepest apologies to Allen Ginsberg. … Not that we're of the same generation…

Answer (score 3):

Replace your `"<10"` and `"<20"` with functions:

```
val a = Map[Int, Int => Boolean](1 -> (_ < 10), 2 -> (_ < 20))
```

And then you can do:

```
b filter { case (k, v) => a(k)(v) }
```

Or equivalently:

```
b filter Function.uncurried(a).tupled
```

Answer (score 3):

Scala is scriptable as well as scalable.  Sort of.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val a=Map(1->"<10",2->"<20")
a: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> <10, 2 -> <20)

scala> val b=List((1,15),(2,15))
b: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,15), (2,15))

scala> import javax.script._
import javax.script._

scala> new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
res0: javax.script.ScriptEngine = scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain@4ba302e0

scala> b filter { case (k, v) => (res0 eval s"$v${a(k)}").asInstanceOf[Boolean] }
res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,15))
```